# Are there any distros that include a binary package for keter?

Tags: deployment, package, yesod, keter

I am preparing to deploy a yesod webapp using keter.

The only instructions to install keter is these: https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2017-07-19/package/keter-1.4.3.2. Which have this suggestion:

> This approach is not recommended for a production system. We do not
> recommend installing a full GHC toolchain on a production server, nor
> running such ad-hoc scripts. This is intended to provide a quick way
> to play with Keter, especially for temporary virtual machines. For a
> production system, we recommend building the keter binary on a
> separate system, and tracking it via a package manager or similar
> strategy.

But have not found a keter pkg in the package manager of my system (ubuntu). Is there some distro which have this package? Or other recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is this [comment](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/issues/77#issuecomment-77204113) to a issue in the keter project.

Here the code and instructions: https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/tree/master/packaging